# Docker very slow in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I have an application running in Elastic Beanstalk (AWS) smoothly and fast, but when I run it in Docker in my local, it takes a long time to load a single page (before it was not like this, it just start happened a few weeks ago). I am working on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I also installed Docker desktop, but it does not matter what I do, the result is always the same (very very slow responses), is there something I can do?

The application is running an **php:7.4.8-apache** image.

This is how I configurated the “Resources”
CPUs: 10
Memory: 26Gb (the host machine has 32Gb)
Swap: 2.5GB ( I tried many different configurations but it does not make any difference)
Disk Image size: 64Gb

And the host machine:

SO: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Memory: 32Gb
Processor Inter Core i7 CPU 2.60ghz
Disk: 1Tb

**DockerFile**

```
FROM php:7.4.8-apache
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION=16.17
ENV USER=www-data
#set our application folder as an environment variable
ENV APP_HOME /var/www/html
ENV PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"
# # Add cake and composer and cake command to system path
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/var/www/html/lib/Cake/Console"
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/var/www/html/vendor/bin"

# COPY apache site.conf file
COPY ./config-dev-server/apache/* /etc/apache2/
COPY ./config-dev-server/php/conf.d/* /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
COPY ./config-dev-server/php/php.ini-development.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# Project structure.
COPY . $APP_HOME

#install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \

    #change uid and gid of apache to docker user uid/gid
    && usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data \
    && mkdir -p  /var/www/html/logs \
    && mkdir -p  /var/www/html/tmp \
    ## Clear cache
    && apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean && apt-get autoremove && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    # Install system dependencies
    && apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until="false" update \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        # git \
        curl \
        npm \
        libpng-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        zip \
        unzip \
        
        # Install PHP extensions
        && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd intl \
        && pecl install xdebug \
        && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
        
        # fix npm - not the latest version installed by apt-get && install amplify
        && npm install -g \
            npm@8.15 \
            @aws-amplify/cli \
        && a2enmod rewrite \
        && curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash \
        && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION} \
        && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION} \
        && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION} \
        && node --version \
        ## rebuild node-sass node
        && npm rebuild node-sass \
        && groupadd docker \
        && usermod -aG docker $USER \
        # && composer install --no-interaction --no-plugins --no-scripts \
        #change ownership of our applications
        && chown -R www-data:www-data $APP_HOME/  \
        # Changing log owner:group and permissions.
        && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/* \
        # change permissions
        && chmod 755 -R $APP_HOME/  \
        && chmod 777 -R /var/log/*  \
        && echo "Development environment ready, please install composer depdencies"
WORKDIR  $APP_HOME/webroot
EXPOSE 8 8080
```

**docker info**

docker info

```
Client:
 Context:    desktop-linux
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.10.2)
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc., v0.2.9)
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc., 0.6.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.19.0)

Server:
 Containers: 2
  Running: 2
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 2
 Server Version: 20.10.17
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc io.containerd.runc.v2
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6
 runc version: v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.10.124-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 10
 Total Memory: 25.46GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: ZXOQ:5FED:TV2Y:KX5O:L7TF:Q626:4COZ:NWJO:WAJH:72ST:KBGC:X7NI
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  hubproxy.docker.internal:5000
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Benchmarking is your friend. Use a full-system profiler like `sysdig`, or `ebpftrace` or `oprofile` or similar -- something that _measures_ where the time is being spent to remove the present need for guesswork.

Answer (score -1):

The main culprit for this issue is the network driver you are using while starting the container

you need to switch to host network driver and not the bridge which is used by default

Try this

```
docker network disconnect bridge <container id>
```

then

```
docker network connect host <container id>
```

if the connect using host fails I would recommend you commit your container or make an image of it as a backup then create a new container using --network flag

eg: I was facing this with ubuntu 18 image in ubuntu 22.04

```
docket run --network=host -it ubuntu:latest bash
```

Comment: I'd consider this diagnosis reasonable if the OP was complaining that they were getting a lower number of requests per second than they expect, but the default driver is perfectly capable of loading a single page in a reasonable amount of time. The problem stated is too severe to be caused by network driver selection.

Comment: what bottleneck would the network driver cause? (usually these are quite high-performance)